# How to combine two queries from same DB with different where clauses?

Tags: sql, where-clause

```
SELECT
    DATE_PART(week, pickup_date) AS Week,
    CAST(pickup_date AS date),
    Sum(pick_up) AS pickup,
    location_id
FROM
    really_large.db
WHERE
    location_id IN ('Location_1', 'Location_2', 'Location_3')
    AND DATE_PART(week, event_pickup_date) IS NOT NULL
    AND pick_up = 1
    AND in_transit = 0
    AND scan_event = 0
    AND delivery = 0
    AND return_datetime_min IS NULL
GROUP BY
    Date_part(week, pickup_date), CAST(pickup_date AS date), location_id
ORDER BY
    Date_part(week, pickup_date) DESC, CAST(pickup_date AS date) DESC, location_id ASC

UNION

SELECT
    DATE_PART(week, pickup_date) AS Week,
    CAST(pickup_date AS date),
    SUM(in_transit) AS In_Transit,
FROM
    really_large.db
WHERE
    location_id IN ('Location_1', 'Location_2', 'Location_3')
    AND DATE_PART(week, event_pickup_date) IS NOT NULL
    AND pick_up = 1
    AND in_transit = 1
    AND scan_event = 0
    AND delivery = 0
    AND return_datetime_min IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    Date_part(week, pickup_date), CAST(pickup_date AS date), location_id
ORDER BY
    Date_part(week, pickup_date) DESC, CAST(pickup_date AS date) DESC, location_id ASC;
```

Union is causing a syntax error.

Ideally this would display

| Week | date | Sum(pickup) | Sum(in_transit) | Location_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 7/18/21 | 72 | 88 | Location_1 |
| 28 | 7/18/21 | 75 | 68 | Location_2 |
| 28 | 7/18/21 | 96 | 72 | Location_3 |
| 27 | 7/14/21 | 76 | 92 | Location_1 |
| 27 | 7/14/21 | 71 | 72 | Location_2 |
| 27 | 7/14/21 | 69 | 81 | Location_3 |

Comment: What precisely is the error message? Please paste it into your question.

Comment: Also is this postgresql? If so please edit the question to add the correct tag for it (alongside the SQL tag)

Comment: You've got a dangling comma in your second select, and missing 'location_id'

Answer (score 3):

Both queries need to return the same number of columns and data types to do a union. Your second query is missing the location_id column.